# Git subtree split: how to save merges history?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I used

```
git subtree split
```

to split directory of my repository with this article: https://shantanoo-desai.github.io/posts/technology/git_subtree/. It worked good with standard commits but all merge commits (like "Merge branch 'xxx' into 'master') were removed. Is there a way to save them?

Comment: [`git subtree split` docs](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3b08839926fcc7cc48cf4c759737c1a71af430c1/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt#L97) say "*The new history includes only the commits (**including merges**) **that affected <prefix>***" Are you sure merge commits touch the subtree?

Comment: for my understanding: @phd "touch" would mean that there was some work on the subtree path **in the merge commit itself** (like a conflict or some _additional_ work)? If that is the case, then most conflict-less merges would not show up.

Comment: @eftshift0 I avoid splitting histories with merges (too fragile for my taste) so I don't know exact meaning. I'd expect merge commits that brought subhistories that touched the subtree.

Comment: @phd Looks like eftshift0 is right or at least merges including subtree (only or with other files) doesn't in history